# how to change one fields value based on the other in redux-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form

I understand there is few other similar questions in stackoverflow but I have been investigating them and none are helping my scenario or at-least I am not getting it so here's my situation:

I have a component(lets call it `MainComponent`) with two inputs inside. The first input is a `checkbox` and the second one is a `picker`(yes the native one). What I am trying to do is when I click one `checkbox` the corresponding `picker` is getting disabled but I can't remove the value of the picker(which i selected when it became enabled) from `redux-form` state. If i select other `checkbox` previous one does get disabled but the value stays.

Note that I am rendering this `MainComponent` multiple times from another component based on some array of objects.

**MainFile.js**

```
categories.map((categoryItem, index)=>
 items.map((item, index)=>
   <Fields names={[${categoryItem.label}, ${categoryItem.label}.${item.label}]}
           component={Inputs}    
))
```

**Inputs.js**

```
<CheckBox ...>
<Picker ...>
```

The checkbox and the picker is setup correctly with the `inputs: {value, onChange}` etc.

I have tried to change value within this `inputs.js` but then I realized it was wrong and it gave me error that i cant change something from render.

What I am trying to achieve is a way when I uncheck the checkbox I want to also change the value of the picker(**The picker data should be removed from the redux-form state**). How can i do that? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever I understood from your question is that you want to update a field in `redux-form`.

`redux-form` has `change` method which can be utilized to update any field value dynamically.

`import { reduxForm, change } from 'redux-form';`

`const mapDispatchToProps = {
    updateField: (field, data) => change( "YOUR_FORM_NAME", field, data )
}`

Would this help?

Comment: well thanks  and yes it a part of the solution I'm looking for. But in this case the I can reset the field data to something but What i am actually looking for is remove that field. I mean when I uncheck the picker data from the form state should be removed. Sorry for my confusing question. I'll edit it now

Comment: You mean, you want to unregister the field from `redux-form` state?

Comment: of the picker field data, yes exactly!

Comment: Thread - https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2325
Docs - https://redux-form.com/6.3.1/docs/api/actioncreators.md/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the picker from the redux state you can use props UnregisterField

Import it into your file

```
import { unregisterField } from 'redux-form';
```

and in your code

```
 this.props.unregisterField(yourFormName, yourFieldName);
```